# MySQL error USING BTREE

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database I have downloaded from my online server and trying to import on my local mysql but its not working showing this syntax error. I cannot find any errors in this query

This is the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE,
>     KEY `idx_p_id` (`p_id`) USING BTREE,
>     KEY ' at line 27

and this is my query:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_a_id` (`a_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_p_id` (`p_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_m_id` (`m_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Just remove ‘USING BTREE’ unless you are using LIKE statments on this field it will revert to default hash indexing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your mysql server version is older and not compatible with the one where the dump was created.
Try to upgrade your mysql server or to export the dump using the `--compatible` option of mysqldump.

You probably need this:

```
mysqldump --compatible=mysql40 ...
```

You also have the option to import the dump to a newer server which you can create locally and re-export there using the comopatible option.

I have also seen people search and replacing stuff in their mysql dump files but this is an ugly approach, but might work for you if you have just this incompatibility.

also format your text a little bit and accept some answers if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 6):

In the version I am using (5.0.51a), `USING BTREE` **is** supported.  However, the syntax differs slightly: at least within a `CREATE TABLE` statement, the `USING BTREE` part must be between the index name and its colums; e.g.

> INDEX ind USING BTREE (col1, col2)

Although the 5.0 manual says the `index_type` may come before *or* after the column definitions, the latter is not accepted.

I can't say anything about the behaviour in version 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found that helped: [Mysql: USING BTREE – Error when dumping from 5.1 and importing to 5.0](http://prattski.com/2010/06/01/mysql-using-btree-error-when-dumping-from-5-1-and-importing-to-5-0/)

Comment: Link in answer is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is different version of the database.
Difference between mysql 5.0 and mysql 5.1

mysql 5.0 -> KEY `idx_p_id` (`p_id`) USING BTREE,

mysql 5.1 -> KEY `idx_p_id` USING BTREE (`p_id`),

Comment: mysql 5.0  and mysql 5.1 were put in the wrong order. Please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your problem may be a result of a MYSQL bug noted in the following link.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25162

Answer (score 1):

In Version 5.1X you can use BTREE but in older versions it is not possible. to use BTREE in older versions like 5.0x you should just set the index and it doesnt have any option.watch [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25162)

You can see what is in version 5.0x below :

```
MyISAM          =>            BTREE

InnoDB          =>            BTREE

MEMORY/HEAP =>            HASH, BTREE

NDB         =>            BTREE, HASH
```