# MYSQL Error #1064 Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting this error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13' at line 11
```

with this with this query:

```
SQL query:

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jml_usergroups` (
    `id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `parent_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Adjacency List Reference Id',
    `lft` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',
    `rgt` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',
    `title` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_usergroup_parent_title_lookup` ( `parent_id` , `title` ) ,
    KEY `idx_usergroup_title_lookup` ( `title` ) ,
    KEY `idx_usergroup_adjacency_lookup` ( `parent_id` ) ,
    KEY `idx_usergroup_nested_set_lookup` ( `lft` , `rgt` ) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =13;
```

Any idea what the problem is? these errors are like the thorns on a rose

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error USING BTREE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767753/mysql-error-using-btree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is ok, your problem is probably that you're trying to run it on a MySQL version earlier than 5.1, [which does not have `USING BTREE`](http://prattski.com/2010/06/01/mysql-using-btree-error-when-dumping-from-5-1-and-importing-to-5-0/).

Comment: Thanks guys - it worked. all I did for future reference was opened up the .sql file and removed 'USING BTREE'

Comment: @CallumPirie Nothing to be sorry for, I had to look it up now too since I've never asked any questions :) Under the number to the left of the answer, there should be the outline of a checkbox. You should be able to click that to accept the answer.